# Prevent Instantation of class outside of this class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I use `Entity Framework` and the generated classes for the `DbContext`. This classes are generated and every change I do is overwritten the next time I refresh my `DbContext`.

Now I override this class to generate the connection to the database dynamically, which works well. But the problem is, that you can create the class with the parameterless constructor as well and this leads to big problems if the connection is not dynamic.
Is there any way to forbid the instantion of the generated class with the parameterless constructor outside of the generated class?

For example:
The generated class without parameter:

```
public partial class SomeConnection : DbContext
{
    public SomeConnection()
        : base("name=myWrongConnection")
    {
       //should not be able to be called!
    }

    // some more generated and needed stuff!
    ...
}
```

And here the class I need to instantiate:

```
public partial class SomeConnection
{
    public SomeConnection(String connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        // only this constructor should be called without changing the parent class...
    }
}
```

Comment: How about an `abstract` base class?

Comment: it is not possible to change the Base class like already mentioned! This class is generated.

Comment: Are you able to create a wrapper class for this class, and then make the wrapper class a singleton class?

Comment: Can you access connection string?

Comment: Your terminology is wrong here, you cannot call partial classes parent/child.

Comment: @Reniuz i access the connection string by passing it as parameter.

Comment: @DavidG I tried to edit the question and hope it's more correct now.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use a factory, but if you absolutely need to prohibit using a wrong instance, a possible workaround would be overriding `OnModelCreating`, so the instance could not be used, even if created with a wrong constructor:

```
public partial class SomeConnection
{
  private readonly bool correctConstructorWasCalled;

  public DerivedContext(string connectionString)
            :base(connectionString)
  {
      correctConstructorWasCalled = true;
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    if (!correctConstructorWasCalled)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Please call the correct constructor.");
    }
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I have found a solution to absolutely deny a specific constructor:

```
public class Guard
{
  public Guard([CallerMemberName] string callerName = null)
  {
    var constructorExpression = (Expression<Func<Prohibited>>)(() => new Prohibited());
    var constructorMethod = (NewExpression) (constructorExpression.Body);

    var stackFrames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
    if (stackFrames.Any(f => f.GetMethod() == constructorMethod.Constructor))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Aha! you are still trying.");
    }
  }
}

public partial class Prohibited : DbContext
{
   public Prohibited()
            : base("wrong connection string")
   {
   }
}

public partial class Prohibited 
{
  private Guard guard = new Guard();

  public Prohibited(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
  {
  }
}
```

`[CallerMemberName]` is needed so the caller frame is not optimized out in Release configurations.

Comment: nice idea for a workaround. But my intention was it even not to offer it to call this constructor.